# Split row data base on timestamp SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day everyone. I have a table as below. Duration is the time from current state to next state.

| Timestamp | State | Duration(minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/9/2022 8:50:00 AM | A | 35 |
| 10/9/2022 9:25:00 AM | B | 10 |
| 10/9/2022 9:35:00 AM | C | ... |

How do I split data at 9:00 AM of each day like below:

| Timestamp | State | Duration(minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/9/2022 8:50:00 AM | A | 10 |
| 10/9/2022 9:00:00 AM | A | 25 |
| 10/9/2022 9:25:00 AM | B | 10 |
| 10/9/2022 9:35:00 AM | C | ... |

Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the DURATION column - it's just duplicated data which will inevitably lead to inconsistencies and makes the programming more difficult.

Comment: What's the logic behind the spilt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a row-generator function to generate extra rows when the timestamp is before `09:00` and the next timestamp is after `09:00` (and calculate the `diff` value rather than storing it in the table):

```
SELECT l.ts AS timestamp,
       t.state,
       ROUND((l.next_ts - l.ts) * 24 * 60, 2) As diff
FROM   (
         SELECT timestamp,
                LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS next_timestamp,
                state
         FROM   table_name
       ) t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT GREATEST(
                  t.timestamp,
                  TRUNC(t.timestamp - INTERVAL '9' HOUR) + INTERVAL '9' HOUR + LEVEL - 1
                ) AS ts,
                LEAST(
                  t.next_timestamp,
                  TRUNC(t.timestamp - INTERVAL '9' HOUR) + INTERVAL '9' HOUR + LEVEL
                ) AS next_ts
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                TRUNC(t.timestamp - INTERVAL '9' HOUR) + INTERVAL '9' HOUR + LEVEL - 1 < t.next_timestamp
       ) l;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Timestamp, State) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-10-09' + INTERVAL '08:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-09' + INTERVAL '09:25' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-09' + INTERVAL '09:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-12' + INTERVAL '09:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TIMESTAMP | STATE | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-09 08:50:00 | A | 10 |
| 2022-10-09 09:00:00 | A | 25 |
| 2022-10-09 09:25:00 | B | 10 |
| 2022-10-09 09:35:00 | C | 1405 |
| 2022-10-10 09:00:00 | C | 1440 |
| 2022-10-11 09:00:00 | C | 1440 |
| 2022-10-12 09:00:00 | C | 35 |
| 2022-10-12 09:35:00 | D | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4HsYPvgo)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, what if I want to add 1 more time such as 3 PM to split the data, now we have 2 points (9AM and 3PM)